# Encrypt name of uploaded file

Tags: php, mysql, html, security

I have an upload script that I found online and modified a little. I need a way to make sure that every file that is uploaded has a unique name; something short at first and as the number of files increase, the length of the name can increase too. My script I've used is...

```
<?php


// Folder to upload files to. Must end with slash /
define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','../uploads/');

// Maximum allowed file size, Kb
// Set to zero to allow any size
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10240);

// Upload success URL. User will be redirected to this page after upload.
define('SUCCESS_URL','my info');

// Allowed file extensions. Will only allow these extensions if not empty.
// Example: $exts = array('avi','mov','doc');
$exts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

// rename file after upload? false - leave original, true - rename to some unique     filename
define('RENAME_FILE', true);

// put a string to append to the uploaded file name (after extension);
// this will reduce the risk of being hacked by uploading potentially unsafe files;
// sample strings: aaa, my, etc.
define('APPEND_STRING', '');

// Need uploads log? Logs would be saved in the MySql database.
define('DO_LOG', true);

// MySql data (in case you want to save uploads log)
define('DB_HOST','my info'); // host, usually localhost
define('DB_DATABASE','my info'); // database name
define('DB_USERNAME','my info'); // username
define('DB_PASSWORD','my info'); // password


/*CREATE TABLE uploads_log (
  log_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  log_filename varchar(128) default '',
  log_size int(10) default 0,
  log_ip varchar(24) default '',
  log_date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY  (log_id),
  KEY (log_filename)
);*/



####################################################################
###  END OF SETTINGS.   DO NOT CHANGE BELOW
####################################################################

// Allow script to work long enough to upload big files (in seconds, 2 days by default)
@set_time_limit(172800);

// following may need to be uncommented in case of problems
// ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","10800");

function showUploadForm($message='') {
  $max_file_size_tag = '';
  if (MAX_FILE_SIZE > 0) {
    // convert to bytes
    $max_file_size_tag = "<input name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='".(MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024)."'     type='hidden' >\n";
  }

  // Load form template
  include ('index.php');
}

// errors list
$errors = array();

$message = '';

// we should not exceed php.ini max file size
$ini_maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
if (!is_numeric($ini_maxsize)) {
  if (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'M') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024*1024;
  elseif (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'K') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024;
  elseif (strpos($ini_maxsize, 'G') !== false)
    $ini_maxsize = intval($ini_maxsize)*1024*1024*1024;
}
if ($ini_maxsize < MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024) {
  $errors[] = "Alert! Maximum upload file size in php.ini (upload_max_filesize) is less     than script's MAX_FILE_SIZE";
}

// show upload form
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  showUploadForm(join('',$errors));
}

// process file upload
else {

  while(true) {

    // make sure destination folder exists
    if (!@file_exists(DESTINATION_FOLDER)) {
      $errors[] = "Destination folder does not exist or no permissions to see it.";
      break;
    }

    // check for upload errors
    $error_code = $_FILES['filename']['error'];
    if ($error_code != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      switch($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
          // uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
          $errors[] = "File is too big (1).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
          // uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in     the HTML form
          $errors[] = "File is too big (2).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
          // uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (1).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
          // No file was uploaded
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (2).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
          // Missing a temporary folder
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (3).";
          break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
          // Failed to write file to disk
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (4).";
          break;
        case 8:
          // File upload stopped by extension
          $errors[] = "Could not upload file (5).";
          break;
      } // switch

      // leave the while loop
      break;
    }

    // get file name (not including path)
    $filename = @basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);

    // filename of temp uploaded file
    $tmp_filename = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

    $file_ext = @strtolower(@strrchr($filename,"."));
    if (@strpos($file_ext,'.') === false) { // no dot? strange
      $errors[] = "Suspicious file name or could not determine file extension.";
      break;
    }
    $file_ext = @substr($file_ext, 1); // remove dot

    // check file type if needed
    if (count($exts)) {   /// some day maybe check also $_FILES['user_file']['type']
      if (!@in_array($file_ext, $exts)) {
        $errors[] = "Files of this type are not allowed for upload.";
        break;
      }
    }

    // destination filename, rename if set to
    $dest_filename = $filename;
    if (RENAME_FILE) {
      $dest_filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . $file_ext;
    }
    // append predefined string for safety
    $dest_filename = $dest_filename . APPEND_STRING;

    // get size
    $filesize = intval($_FILES["filename"]["size"]); // filesize($tmp_filename);

    // make sure file size is ok
    if (MAX_FILE_SIZE > 0 && MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024 < $filesize) {
      $errors[] = "File is too big (3).";
      break;
    }

    if (!@move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename , DESTINATION_FOLDER . $dest_filename)) {
      $errors[] = "Could not upload file (6).";
      break;
    }

    if (DO_LOG) {
      // Establish DB connection
      $link = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
      if (!$link) {
        $errors[] = "Could not connect to mysql.";
        break;
      }
      $res = @mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link);
      if (!$res) {
        $errors[] = "Could not select database.";
        break;
      }
      /*$m_ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
     $m_size = $filesize;
      $m_fname = mysql_real_escape_string($dest_filename);
      $sql = "insert into _uploads_log (log_filename,log_size,log_ip) values     ('$m_fname','$m_size','$m_ip')";
      $res = @mysql_query($sql);
      if (!$res) {
        $errors[] = "Could not run query.";
        break;
      }*/
      @mysql_free_result($res);
      @mysql_close($link);
    } // if (DO_LOG)


   // redirect to upload success url
    header('Location: ' . SUCCESS_URL);
    die();

    break;

  } // while(true)

  // Errors. Show upload form.
  $message = join('',$errors);
  showUploadForm($message);

}

?>
```

Plus, what other security procedures should I use? If you know any, could you please implement them into my code and re-post them? Thank you!!!

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Also, when posting code, please trim anything that isn't relevant to your question. Preferably, your code should be a [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted already includes the lines:

```php
if (RENAME_FILE) {
  $dest_filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . $file_ext;
}
```

This is a perfectly good way to generate a random unique file name in PHP.  The string returned by `md5()` will be 32 characters long; you could safely truncate it a bit, but if you go much below 16 characters or so, you start risking collisions.

Of course, if you want to make *sure* there are no collisions, you could always just check whether the file exist and retry if it does.  This would even allow you to use shorter filenames:

```php
if (RENAME_FILE) {
  do {
    $dest_filename = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 8) . ".$file_ext";
  } while (file_exists(DESTINATION_FOLDER . $dest_filename . APPEND_STRING));
}
```

This should give you a unique 8-character (+ extension) filename.  Of course, this will start slowing down after about 2<sup>31</sup> ≈ 2 billion uploaded files, and will fail completely at 2<sup>32</sup> ≈ 4 billion.

Comment: Will it work if I change the 8 in the code to something like 16? Will that give me the ability to have more than 4 million uploads?

Comment: Yes, with 16 chars you'll be good for up to about 2^63 = 8 quadrillion uploads. You're going to run out of disk space way before that.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I screwed up a factor of 1000: even for 8 chars, the limit is about 2 _billion_ files ([short scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales)), not 4 million. With 16 chars you can go up to about 8 quintillion.

Comment: @JustinMiller If it's "Perfect", then you should **accept this answer**, if it did in fact solve your problem.